# How to rewrite a string by pattern

Tags: c#, string, iterator, string-formatting

I have a string, where the "special areas" are enclosed in curly braces:

```
{intIncG}/{intIncD}/02-{yy}
```

I need to iterate through all of these elements inbetween {} and replace them based on their content. What is the best code structure to do it in C#?

I can't just do a replace since I need to know the index of each "speacial area {}" in order to replace it with the correct value.

Comment: just the index? You're not changing the replace based upon the content inside the {}?

Comment: Both need to come into consideration - an index and a contents - the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex( @"\({[^\}]*\})");
string output = rgx.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(DoStuff));


static string DoStuff(Match match)
{
//Here you have access to match.Index, and match.Value so can do something different for Match1, Match2, etc.
//You can easily strip the {'s off the value by 

   string value = match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length-2);

//Then call a function which takes value and index to get the string to pass back to be susbstituted

}
```

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't the line `input.Replace(match.Groups[i].Value, GetValueForIndex(i));` fail in case I will have a string in a form `{intInc_G}/{intInc_G}/{yy}`. It would replace both occurrences of a substring, whereas I need to have the only one replaced - the one at the currently processed index.

Comment: Much more elegant then my "by-hand" approach I've written. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`string.Replace` will do just fine.

```
var updatedString = myString.Replace("{intIncG}", "something");
```

Do once for every different string.

---

Update:

Since you need the index of `{` in order to produce the replacement string (as you [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449691/how-to-split-a-string-by-pattern/11449720#comment15109837_11449720)), you can use `Regex.Matches` to *find* the indices of `{` - each [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) object in the `Matches` collection will include the index in the string.

Comment: My bad, I can't just do this becuase I need to know the index of a special area in order to form a correct "something". I should have mentioned it in a question. Now I've added this requirement. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Replaces all occurrences of a character pattern defined by a regular expression with a specified replacement character string.

from msdn

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function and join it's output -- so you'll only need to traverse the parts once and not for every replace rule.

```
private IEnumerable<string> Traverse(string input)
{
  int index = 0;
  string[] parts = input.Split(new[] {'/'});
  foreach(var part in parts)
  {
    index++;
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    switch(part)
    {
      case "{intIncG}":
        retVal = "a"; // or something based on index!
        break;
      case "{intIncD}":
        retVal = "b"; // or something based on index!
        break;

      ...
    }
    yield return retVal;
  }
}

string replaced = string.Join("/", Traverse(inputString));
```